# How can I config broker to talk to other nodes? (Docker)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I create 3 broker nodes and 3 zookeeper nodes with docker-compose.yml, when I create the topics or produce and comesume message it's show "**WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -2 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (or g.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)**"

It's seem like leader broker and follower can't connect to each other.
How can I fix this?

Comment: It'd be great if you could show your compose file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the listeners and set the listener for inter broker communication. An example:

```
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka:9094
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
```